# Node.js delete photos not working

Tags: node.js

I have tried several methods to delete my photo, especially using `fs.unlink` but it seems not working at all, you can see from picture below that i save my photos in `assets->img->products`

[image]

and so my database looks like this
[image]

and my code looks like this

```
router.get("/admin/products/:id/delete", (req, res) => {
    Product.findByIdAndRemove(req.params.id, (err, photo) => {
    if (err) {
    req.flash("error", "deleting photo failed");
       return res.render("/admin/products/");
    }
    fs.unlink(photo.image1, function() {
      console.log(photo.image1);
      return res.redirect("/admin/products");
    });
  });
});
```

what is wrong from my code that did not delete my photo from my file?

Comment: What *is* the error?

Comment: there is no error at all, all the data succesfully deleted, but my photo not

Comment: Aside: `fs.unlink` will get called if you have no error, as well as when you do have an error. Add `return` before `res.render("/admin/products/");` as in `return res.render("/admin/products/");` to prevent the 2nd case.

Comment: @Mikey it is not an error, i have `console.log(err)` if it's an error, yet all the data is deleted but my photo still exist in my folder assets, and i have did what u asked me to write `return`, still same

Comment: My comment was a remark regarding that you are not safely stopping if you were to have an error with your findByIdAndRemove.

Comment: @Mikey ahh i see, oke haha, then i should do it for the rest of my code

Comment: Have you checked the error object that is provided as the first argument of your [fs.unlink callback](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_unlink_path_callback)? My bet is you probably are not pointing to the right path from your current file.

Comment: @Mikey there are no error, the first argument is my path which is the `console.log(photo.image1)` = `/assets/img/products/image1-1524457186384.jpg`

Comment: The first argument to the callback you pass to `fs.unlink()` is an error parameter.  You should be logging what that is.  It probably tells you `ENOENT` because it can't find the path you're giving it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It can not delete photos because you are passing the relative path as the first parameter.

> photo.image1 = assets/img/products/image1.jpg

Try passing the passing the absolute path( from the root directory of your machine).

```
fs.unlink("absolute-path-to-assetsParentFolder" + photo.image1, function() {
  console.log(photo.image1);
  return res.redirect("/admin/products");
});
```

Comment: i did something like that, `const path = _dirname + '/assets/';
then do something like you suggest, but not working, am i should use express static? to solve this issues

Comment: express static is used to designate a folder to serve static files. It won't help. Use absolute path instead of __dirname. In case of linux use /home/path-to-folder/ + photo.image1. Other method is to use console.log(_dirname) to see the folder it refers to, then you can adjust the path.

Comment: still working on it sir, ill let you know as soon as i manage to do it

Comment: so i take a closer look in my path, tursn out i need to go back 1 folder and it works,